# Tiles with long description

Tags: modal

[image]

We have several project tiles where the user can see long (500 char) description and take action (Like) on each tile. They're presented as grid view (as shown below) or list view (using full width with thumbnail on left).

However, a team member suggested that toggling the description like this is rather *unorthodox* but I'm sure I have seen similar interaction somewhere just can't remember.

So just wondering if this is good design and/or what are the options beside showing the description in a modal?

Comment: Have you considered making the tile scrollable?

Comment: Yes, the issue is not the length of the text but the very idea of showing description in the card itself.

Comment: Your question is about options beside showing in a modal. I'm assuming you a) want to show a the description at all, and b) want to show it in the context of the card (i.e. you don't want to link somewhere else). When I say scrolling, I mean instead of appearing over top of the image/title/button, the description could appear to slide up. Another pattern I've see here is the rotation of the card i.e. the click makes the card spin on an axis to reveal the description behind.

Answer (score 4):

Talking about cards, Material Design does the following

[image: Material Design Cards]

https://material.io/guidelines/components/cards.html#cards-content-blocks

Generally speaking, the expected behavior of the **button "Read more"** is that the user is directed to another page. In the case of the **link "Read more"**, it is expected that more text will be shown in the same place.

My recommendation is to make your interaction more like the one in Material Design.

Answer (score 1):

The toggle will confuse users, because all the information of the item is replaced by the detailed text. I recommend using a pattern similar to the one used by amazon:

[image]

If it is difficult to use the above pattern, then at least repeat the title and the subtitle on the detailed description :

[image]